# For my selectlist with multiple values per entry, how can I handle empty entries?

Tags: c#, .net-core

```
var studentInfo = _context.Student
    .Select(s =>
    new
    {
        Id = s.Id,
        Name = s.FirstName + " " + s.SurName + " " + s.LastName + " - " + s.StudentCode
    });

ViewBag.Students = new SelectList(studentInfo, "Id", "Name");
```

This is my code, it works fine for people who have a surname. But if the surname is empty, the selectlist entry displays no information at all, how can I prevent this?

Comment: `s.SurName.GetValueOrDefault("")` maybe? This should return an empty string if `s.SurName` is `null`. (Is this LinqToEntity or LinqToSql?)

Comment: Do you mean FirstOrDefault? This didn't work, anyways it has been solved , thanks for your time!

Comment: No, I meant [GetValueOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault?view=netframework-4.8), but it apparently does not work with `string`

Comment: @OmarRuder If your question has been answered, please post the answer or accept any posted answer, so others can learn from this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way:

```
var studentInfo = _context.Student
    .Select(s =>
    new
    {
        Id = s.Id,
        Name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.SurName)
            ? s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName + " - " + s.StudentCode
            : s.FirstName + " " + s.SurName + " " + s.LastName + " - " + s.StudentCode
    });

ViewBag.Students = new SelectList(studentInfo, "Id", "Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

This might also work - including removing the leftover spaces if *SurName* is not there :)

```
var students = new List<Student>() 
{ 
    new Student() { FirstName = "John", SurName = "Wick", LastName = "Doe", StudenCode = "666" }, 
    new Student() { FirstName = "James", LastName = "Bond", StudenCode = "0007" } 
};

var formattedStudents = students.Select(p => new { Name = Regex.Replace($"{p.FirstName} {p.SurName} {p.LastName} - {p.StudenCode}", 
                                                                        @"\s+"," ", 
                                                                        RegexOptions.Compiled) });
```